# PrimeNG Calendar dynamic placement/positioning

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm using PrimeNG Calendar/date picker with Angular and only have one complaint.

When I click an input where the calendar is supposed to popup, it doesn't position itself dynamically. If I have a lot of room on the screen above the input and very little below it, the calendar still pops up below the input and gets cut off.

When I used JQuery UI's date picker, it would position itself dynamically based on where there was more room, so it was much less likely to get cutoff.

Is there a way to get PrimeNG Calendar/Date Picker to behave the same way and position itself above or below the input dynamically based on where there is more room?

I searched through [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) but didn't see anything about this issue.

Comment: Any fixes for this? I had to go through renderer2, and it was a very hacky solution.

Comment: @Jeff Not that I found, so I stopped using it.

Comment: I ended up using a global CSS ruleset of `.offset-calendar-popup .p-datepicker { transform: translateX(-100%); }` on the popup for cases where the popup is close to the right edge of the screen.

Comment: For me `.offset-calender-popup` not working. I used `.p-datepicker { transform: translateX(-100%); }`

Answer (score 1):

I am working with PrimeNG Calendar version 7.2.6-lts and I had the same issue.
I solved by using the **appendTo** attribute, as shown below:

```
<p-calendar formControlName="myFormControlName" appendTo="body"></p-calendar>
```

As stated by the [PrimeNG documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v7-lts/#/calendar):

> **Property name:** appendTo
>
> **Type:** any
>
> **Default:** null
>
> **Description:** Target element to attach the overlay, valid values are "body" or a local ng-template variable of another element.

I did not check but it should work with newer versions too.